# Show input in Symbolic form without computation in Maxima

Tags: maxima

In Maxima when I enter for example:

[image]

I can see my input in a "readable" way, in order to verify everything I have typed in is interpreted the way I want. I want to be able to at first see my input in symbolic form and after that the result of my computation. For example when I define x as 5 I want the same result as above and after that the simplified form.

[image]

Is that possible? I use wxmaxima.

Another simple example for illustration: When I enter `5*5` I want an output saying `5 5` and then a second output with `25`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can get the effect you want by disabling simplification.

```
(%i1) simp:false;
(%o1)                                false
(%i2) x:5;
(%o2)                                  5
(%i3) 34*sqrt(x+ 7)/(7*x^2);
                                34 sqrt(5 + 7)
(%o3)                           --------------
                                        2
                                     7 5
(%i4) %, simp;
                                  68 sqrt(3)
(%o4)                             ----------
                                     175
```

Simplification, in Maxima, means applying arithmetic and algebraic identities. Many important operations such as adding and multiplying numbers are carried out by simplification in Maxima, so if you disable simplification, you will get results that are pretty different from what you would get with simplification enabled. But you can get the usual result by simplifying it, as in %i3 above.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wanted, I just needed to know how to do this in order to better inspect my input, when I disable simplification the input is displayed (in wxMaxima) in a very good readable form. Thank you