# Manipulate maxima output to show numerical fractions before variable

Tags: maxima

Say I have the following polynomial:

```
(3/4) * x^2 - (1/2) *x  + 3/4;
```

Maxima output (also the tex output) would show this as:

```
(%i1) (3/4) * x^2 - (1/2) *x  + 3/4;
                                    2
                                 3 x    x   3
(%o1)                            ---- - - + -
                                  4     2   4
```

But I want the fractions before the variables. Like this:

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: There is answer a few posts below :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375539/show-input-in-symbolic-form-without-computation-in-maxima

Comment: I don't think this does what I want, for example if I do:
`diff((3/4) * x^2 - (1/2) *x  + 3/4, x), simp: false;` In other words, I do want to calculations that use the simplify thing, but I want the end form to be in the above stated form. I want too much I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pfeformat:true;` Does that help?

Comment: nice! note that now `tex((3/4) * x^2 - (1/2) *x  + 3/4);` outputs exactly the image in the OP (when rendered with TeX, off course).